# Which process is accessing the SD card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi3 Model  B+ that is used as a backup server.

The backup tool is configured to write all data to an external NTFS formatted drive. However, the SD card is constantly accessed (written on and/or read from) as indicated by the flashing green LED (irregular pattern).

How can I find out, which process is causing this?

I tried using `iostat`, however that only confirms that the SD card is constantly in use:

```
  tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn Device
 7.59       493.9k        27.0k      41.1G       2.2G mmcblk0
28.16       695.5k         1.4M      57.9G     118.9G sda
```

(kB_read and kB_wrtn are accumulated values over ~24 hours)

Another tool that I tried is `iotop`, but this gives me only information on all processing that are causing IO traffic, but it cannot distinguish between SD card and external NTFS formatted drive.
Processes listed here include:

- `urbackup` (the backup tool, configured to use the external drive as a tmp directory and backup target, backup sources are other PCs on the LAN)
- some `kworker/u8:0+flush-8:0` or similar processes which I don't know about
- `mount.ntfs-3g`

As the SD card is constantly accessed I am worried about it beeing destroyed in the near future.

Any ideas what is causing this or how can find this out?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of success with the output of `lsof` which has data correlating a PID with the file that's being opened.  That's how I ended up figuring out that my flash drive kept blinking whenever I looked at it because I had accidentally set motion up to start on boot up.  It was quite a creepy effect!

Answer (score 0):

The SD card is accessed twice a second to check that it is still inserted.

This results in a very brief LED flash twice a second which most people don't even seem to notice.

Comment: In my case, this is note the case. The green LED is flashing in an irregular pattern and `iostat` confirms that a lot of data is written/read. I just updated my question with the actual output of iostat.

Comment: @user1251007 That's fine now,